# How to stop a Word macro loop at the end of a document?

Tags: microsoft-word, vba

I have a large set of documents where the headings are numbered manually. I set the heading styles to number automatically, but now I want to delete the manual numbers.

So I have the following macro (for Heading 2) that finds 'Heading 2' and removes the manual numbers, then repeats the action.

Problem is that it doesn't stop at the end of the document. How do I get the macro to terminate when it reaches the end of the document?

Here's the code:

```
Sub FixHeading2()
'
' FixHeading2 Macro fixes he numbering for Heading 2
'
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 2")
Selection.Find.Execute
While Selection.Find.Found
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdWord, Count:=3, Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    Selection.Find.Execute
Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please share some sample text too?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set `.Wrap` property of `.Find`

```
...
Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 2")
Selection.Find.Wrap = wdFindStop
...
```

> Find.Wrap Property:
>
> Returns or sets what happens if the search begins
>   at a point other than the beginning of the document and the end of the
>   document is reached (or vice versa if Forward is set to False) or if
>   the search text isn't found in the specified selection or range.
>   Read/write WdFindWrap.

from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192810.aspx)

Comment: That didn't work. The macro just went ahead and deleted all my Heading 2's completely, and Word crashed when I tried to stop it. The documents were created by Flare, so heading numbering is inserted as text" 1.1 Heading 2", then "1.2 Next Heading" and so on. I want to replace the text '1.1' and '1.2' to auto numbering, so they will update when I edit the document. These are long documents with multiple headings from chapters (Heading 1) to Heading 4.